# "Internet Explorer 8" autocomplete password encryption method

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer 8 encrypts form autocomplete passwords and stores them in the Registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IntelliForms. I understsand that the URL of the site is used in the encrption process.

Does anyone know what the encryption mechanisn is - 3DES?

Comment: Why is it that you are asking?

Comment: Thanks but this only points out where the settings are held, not what the encryption algorithm is

Comment: Why am I asking? Because at my company someone is able to save passwords and our security people want to know ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: it's 168bit 3DES. [Blog post with full details here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/09/restoring-the-internet-explorer-password-autocomplete-prompt.aspx).